# Get ::placeholder color using Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

Is it possible to get current color value of an `input` placeholder text?
Usually I'd use `getComputedStyle` to get current element style values, but it does not return the placeholder value.

Any workarounds for this apart from parsing the css text and getting the value using regex?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

the second parameter of `getComputedStyle` is pseudoElt selector

so to get placeholder color of your input element:

```
var styles = window.getComputedStyle(inputEl, ':placeholder');
console.log(styles.getPropertyValue('color'));
```

Comment: reference, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

Comment: Legend - this is exactly what I needed!

Comment: This is exactly what I needed too, but unfortunately this is no longer supported. Check the "Note" callout on the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) page.

"...the latest W3 standard explicitly supports only ::before and ::after, while the CSS WG draft does not restrict this value.  Browser compatibility may vary."

Comment: Does not work in Firerfox

Answer (score 2):

It's

```
window.getComputedStyle(inputEl, '::placeholder').getPropertyValue("color");
// note the DOUBLE colon here ----^^
```

Works in both Chrome and Firefox

Answer (score -2):

Usually placeholder we have to use a class name and then change the placeholder color

```
input.text-filed::-webkit-input-placeholder {
   color: red;
}
```

So u know the class which is have the color

Comment: Even so, how would you get the current color (red, in this case), from the element itself?

Comment: Hi u can specify the placeholder for a particular input field and placeholder color for that clas , so based on condition u can check color , refer my plunker      http://plnkr.co/edit/X0CYpUx3Lcijd0wkirBL?p=preview

Comment: Ok, I understand the confusion - My goal is to analyze websites not under my control (developing a Chrome extension for devs), so I don't know in advance what might be the colors.